# How can I avoid CSP errors when evaluating javascript via splash?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, scrapy, content-security-policy, scrapy-splash

am scraping data from "https://www.welcometothejungle.com/en"

```
  function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("#sticky-menu a[data-testid=menu-jobs]").click()'))
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
  end
```

I encountered this error JS error: 'EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline' cdn.welcometothejungle.co

```
 {
"error": 400,
"type": "ScriptError",
"description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
"info": {
    "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]",
    "line_number": 4,
    "error": "JS error: 'EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because \\'unsafe-eval\\' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: \"script-src \\'unsafe-inline\\' cdn.welcometothejungle.co platform.linkedin.com www.linkedin.com www.googletagmanager.com tagmanager.google.com www.google-analytics.com connect.facebook.net www.facebook.com www.youtube.com *.ytimg.com loader.wisepops.com app.wisepops.com cdn.wisepops.com optimize.google.com app.getbeamer.com realtime.getbeamer.com player.vimeo.com speakerdeck.com www.slideshare.net talks.golang.org docs.google.com slides.com static.hotjar.com script.hotjar.com *.batch.com polyfill.io *.axept.io\".\\n'",
    "type": "LUA_ERROR",
    "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:4: JS error: 'EvalError: 
       Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because \\'unsafe-eval\\' is not an allowed source of 
       script in the following Content Security Policy directive: \"script-src \\'unsafe-inline\\' 
       cdn.welcometothejungle.co platform.linkedin.com www.linkedin.com www.googletagmanager.com 
       tagmanager.google.com www.google-analytics.com connect.facebook.net www.facebook.com 
       www.youtube.com *.ytimg.com loader.wisepops.com app.wisepops.com cdn.wisepops.com 
       optimize.google.com app.getbeamer.com realtime.getbeamer.com player.vimeo.com speakerdeck.com 
       www.slideshare.net talks.golang.org docs.google.com slides.com static.hotjar.com 
       script.hotjar.com *.batch.com polyfill.io *.axept.io\".\\n'"
         }
       }
```

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

> error JS error: 'EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline' cdn.welcometothejungle.co ...

This error caused by `assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("#sticky-menu a[data-testid=menu-jobs]").click()'))`

The *splash:[runjs](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/blob/master/splash/engines/webkit/browser_tab.py)('string')* internally calls *evaljs('string')* -> calls native JavaScript's `eval()` func to convert string to JS code.

Content Security Policy prohibits to use JavaScript's eval-expressions without `'unsafe-eval'` token in the `script-src` directive.

You have to add `'unsafe-eval'` token into `script-src`:

```
"script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' cdn.welcometothejungle.co platform.linkedin.com
www.linkedin.com www.googletagmanager.com tagmanager.google.com
www.google-analytics.com connect.facebook.net www.facebook.com www.youtube.com
*.ytimg.com loader.wisepops.com app.wisepops.com cdn.wisepops.com
optimize.google.com app.getbeamer.com realtime.getbeamer.com player.vimeo.com
speakerdeck.com www.slideshare.net talks.golang.org docs.google.com slides.com
static.hotjar.com  script.hotjar.com *.batch.com polyfill.io *.axept.io"
```

Comment: could you please show me how to modify the function exactly by adding CSP

Comment: I do not know how exactly you publish CSP. But in the error '"message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:4: JS error: 'EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because ...' I see that CSP is publushed some way. You have to figure out how you did it and add `'unsafe-eval'` token to `script-src` directive.